# Style of UITableViewCells in search display controller

Tags: uitableview, uisearchbar

How can I style the `UITableViewCell`s displayed in the search results for the "Search Bar + Search Display Controller" option?

My table cells have a custom height, background font etc. However the table cells displayed in the search results have the default height etc.

Comment: Each cell has a contentView. When you create the cell the first time in code, and set its identifier, you may add any views that you wish in the cell by accessing `[cell.contentView addSubview:(UIView *)]`. Later you may access and change those views using `[cell.contentView.subviews objectAtIndex:(NSInteger)]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you just want to set the height, you can modify directly over the property [rowHeight](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableView/rowHeight) of your UITableView

```
tableView.rowHeight = 60;
```

if you need different heights depending on your data: add a [UITableViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) Implementation

```
{
    //...
    tableView.delegate = self;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // ask your data what height they have
    return 60;
}
```